# Roll n 3-sided dice (ABC). How do I calculate the probability of at least one A

Tags: probability

Suppose I have n three-sided dice, with sides labelled A, B, C. How do I calculate the probability of getting at least one A among the dice ? All possible combination of an A is
valid ABC, ABB,ACC,AAB,AAC,AAA. The order doesn't matter.

For example:

- for n = 2 total number of outcomes is 9 and the probability of getting at least an A is 5/9. I can easily draw a table and count the number of times there is A, this becomes harder as n becomes larger. Is there a way to calculate the probability of getting an A when n is greater than 2 ?

Comment: Go for finding the probability of the complement (i.e. no A appears).

Comment: Thanks @drhab, How does one the probability of the complement ?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks